# Append\Union two or several tables into one

Tags: r, union, read.table

I input 5 text data sets into R using `read.table`. 
Each data set has the same structure (100 rows,  50 cols).
I would like to union\append all the five tables together into one table, which will be 500 rows * 50 cols.
Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Fyi, that is not what union means.

Comment: I have try union, but it become a large list, no longer a table.

Comment: I cast a vote to reopen this question as I don't think this is too broad, as the OP has accepted an answer that makes it clear what they mean by `union`, that is, an SQL `union`. FWIW, I was looking up `how to do a union of sql tables from dplyr` and google pointed me to this question as the first result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In base R, you can do the following:

```
# Create some toy data first
nc <- 50
nr <- 1000

# Create five tables with nc columns and nr rows.
df1 <- as.data.frame(replicate(nc, rnorm(nr)))
df2 <- as.data.frame(replicate(nc, rnorm(nr)))
df3 <- as.data.frame(replicate(nc, rnorm(nr)))
df4 <- as.data.frame(replicate(nc, rnorm(nr)))
df5 <- as.data.frame(replicate(nc, rnorm(nr)))

# Join the tables
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
dim(df)
#[1] 5000   50
```

This gives you the 5 tables stacked upon each other if that's what you're looking for. If not, 
you should provide at minimal example illustrating your problem.

Comment: Thank you. It is what I am looking for. I am new to R.

Answer (score 16):

From package `dplyr`:

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
new_df <- bind_rows(table1, table2, table3, table4, table5)
```

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either. Actually `bind_rows` is much more efficient than `rbind`.

Comment: I also do not see a problem, so upvote from here. Maybe someone thinks it *overkill* to use a package for such a simple problem. While it is faster in general (as @Psidom points out) the data size is so small that it doesn't matter in practice here (probably).

Comment: But dplyr is so awesome.... :)

Comment: AEBilgrau's way works. But I also try your way. I install the package and use bind_rows to bind tables. But the it has Error: could not find function "bind_rows". Then I use dplyr::bind_rows, then there is another error: Warning messages:
1: In rbind_all(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character. In the final dataset, parts of rows are missing.

Comment: You have to install the package first.  I will edit the code above to include that.  I am unaware of what would be causing that error, however.

Answer (score 7):

Even though it does not matter for this specific question, it might be still helpful to have a comparison of different rbind methods. Here is a comparison of three `rbind` methods from `base`, `data.table` and `dplyr`;

```
> dim(df)
[1] 16777216        2

> microbenchmark(rbind(df,df), rbindlist(list(df,df)), bind_rows(df,df), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
           rbind(df, df) 3824.4208 4052.6405 4288.5569 4239.2416 4557.5736 4685.2155    10   c
 rbindlist(list(df, df))  272.5048  304.8365  348.0393  357.4388  390.7684  405.0778    10 a  
       bind_rows(df, df)  571.1732  596.2556  715.1572  643.8038  863.5805  927.0341    10  b
```

Comment: Thank you, Psidom.